# How to get rid of "Unable to find explicit activity class" error even after declaring the activity in AndroidManifest.xml file?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I tried navigating from Main activity to the "second activity", but as soon as it switches the app gets crashed. Please note that I have included the new activity in AndroidManifests.xml

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.textme">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.TextMe"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".SecondActivity"/>


        
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Why does it still show error?

```
com.example.textme E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.textme, PID: 22401
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.textme/java.lang.String}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2256)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1914)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5326)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:705)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5284)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:686)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5670)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5623)
        at com.example.textme.MainActivity.onCreate$lambda-1(MainActivity.kt:25)
        at com.example.textme.MainActivity.$r8$lambda$maNhvr12gpIoBBKbBDtjW2g9MFQ(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.example.textme.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7520)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1194)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7489)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:826)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28555)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8024)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:631)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:978)
```

Comment: How are you trying to start the second activity?

Comment: Is `SecondActivity` declared in the `com.example.textme` package?

Comment: `val next: Button = findViewById(R.id.next)
        next.setOnClickListener {

            val intent = Intent(this, "SecondActivity"::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
`

Clicking a button should start the second activity

Answer (score 0):

`Intent(Context packageContext, Class<?> cls)`'s second argument should be `Class<?>`.
Unfortunately, when you provide `java.lang.String` as argument, compiler will not complain about it.
`"SecondActivity"::class.java is java.lang.String`

However, Android System will try to create an activity instance from `java.lang.String` which you did not declare in your AndroidManifest.xml.

```kotlin
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class 
{com.example.textme/java.lang.String}; 
have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

When you put quotes arrond `SecondActivity` you make it just a string.
Please, see the correction below.

```kotlin
 val next: Button = findViewById(R.id.next)
 next.setOnClickListener { 
  // this provides String for second argument
  // val intent = Intent(this, "SecondActivity"::class.java)

  // correct call for activity start
  val intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
  startActivity(intent)
}
```

> Please note that I have included the new activity in AndroidManifests.xml

This kind of little errors happen all the time. First thing I do is read the error messages carefully.

Hope it helps.